# Read file in android app takes too much time

Tags: java, android, file-io

I'm writing a Hangman app for android and I encounter some loading problems.
When my app starts, I generate a random word picked from a txt file. The problem is that this file is heavy: it has almost 360'000 words (4000 kB), therefore picking a single word takes between 10 and 20 secs time, I know that it is because I read the file and pick a word each time I click on Generate.

Would it be a good thing if I read the file once the app starts and put its contents into a String Array? I don't really know if an array can handle this much.
Otherwise what would be the good pattern?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: post your picking code, there is probably much to optimize there. (one option, for instance : make it an sqlite db, copy it at startup, make a select order by random, another option : make your lines fixed width, and make a skip(length * rand()) to select your word)

Comment: your array would be 8000 kb (each char being 2 bytes) + 360000 * a few bytes for the string object, you can round it to approx 10Mb, which is way to much to be considered kept in memory. plus, the loading would still take your 10-20 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the code to parse/load content form json/db in a AsyncTask for more speed. I load 5000 rows with ~ 400 chars per row. It takes without AsyncTask much longer.

```
    private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... s) {

            //Here you have to make the loading / parsing tasks
            //Don't call any UI actions here. For example a Toast.show() this will couse Exceptions
            // UI stuff you have to make in onPostExecute method

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // This method will called during doInBackground is in process
            // Here you can for example show a ProgressDialog
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            // onPostExecute is called when doInBackground finished
            // Here you can for example fill your Listview with the content loaded in doInBackground method

        }

}
```

To execute you just have to call:

```
new YourTask().execute("");
```

Here you can learn more about AsyncTasks:

[AsyncTask developer Guide](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html&ei=XXWvUJivB8XIswajxIDABg&usg=AFQjCNE8gLVXz1Hwq4rI8oxRkZNHjhRzpQ&sig2=CmICU1zanbO_qVgO4V9uEg)

Comment: Sorry for my late response, I came along with this solution finally but I still have a problem: I'd like to put a progressbar to notify the user that the file is loading but how to deal with it since I unserialize an object? My idea would be to launch a thread which would increment a counter while the serialisation is not ready.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the whole file into a string array is not a good strategy, since this would consume a lot of memory. One simple solution would be to split your large file up into several single files (using a pattern for the file names, like words1.txt, words2.txt etc). When drawing a word, you would first pick the file and then pick the actual word form the file.

Answer (score 1):

Store it as a CSV, (comma separated values). Open a read stream, seek to a random position and read a small chunk of characters, until you hit `','` twice. Now, extract that word between commas from the string you have read. Also You can have a custom delimiter like '#' or '|' instead of comma.

Update: Use [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

Update2: [`readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readLine%28%29) makes this even more easy, if you store one word per line. I.e. separated by `\n`

Comment: Why not use the existing delimiter (presumably '\n')?  Replacing '\n' with ',' doesn't really change anything, and it makes the file harder to edit.  Other than that, I like the idea of seeking to location N and then scanning forward for the start of a word.  (It means that long words are statistically more likely to be picked than short words, but that may not be of concern here.)

Answer (score 0):

You can (and probably is best to) create a database of the words and query it for the random word. You can start by reading [Saving Data in SQL Databases](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Answer (score 0):

File read is an expensive operation and it is normal for it to take that long. You should probably create a group of files instead of one file and every time you start an app, you can select a random file and a random word from that. That should reduce the time it takes.

Also, you can store the word names in an XML file as an App resource which goes into /res/values/ folder. You can create String Array Resources and easily fetch it from your code without having to worry about opening/closing/reading the file. It is pretty much straight-forward. But it is again important for you to split all your words into different xml files (or at least string array groups) here. Read more here. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

Or an alternative would be to store everything into your DB by reading it from the file. This way, it takes time only for the first launch of the app. You can show a message like, "Preparing DB..." or something of that sort while you're at it.

Answer (score 0):

Some things to take note of here:

1. If your app reads from the SD Card, the quality of the SD Card is actually a factor - there are different read/write speeds depending on the Class of the SD Card you're using - look it up.
2. You mentioned that you're picking a random line in the file every time you click Generate - since you can be sure that the user will be clicking Generate more than once, it's a sound idea to read that file once, store the contents somewhere (sqlite), and the next time you need to get a random word, get it from the stored data. This way you'll limit the number of times you're reading from external storage (which is in mobile standards, a heavy task) to One per application launch.
3. You can even place a marker on your file to let you know if the contents has changed. Anything from a random string to Current Date to an md5 checksum should let you know that you don't need to read the file again, because you've read it before already and stored the contents in your sqlite db. You want to put this on the first line of your file.
4. Now that everyone else is telling you to consider writing to an sqlite db or even copying a .db file itself (which you can generate separately), picking a random item would be trivial. I'd rather warn you about writing 360,000 entries in your database. Using the default ContentProvider `insert(Uri, ContentValues)` method will work, but I won't be surprised if that takes longer than actually parsing through the file itself. The trick here is to override the implementation of ContentProvider's `bulkInsert(Uri, ContentValues[])`, using compiled statements instead. The default implementation only calls the `insert` method multiple times, therefore opening and closing your SqliteDatabase object every insert. What you want to do is call `beginTransaction` at the top, have a for loop that `insert`s each of the items in ContentValues, `setTransactionSuccessful`, then call `endTransaction`.